# Scope of variable instantiated inside a method - Java

Tags: java, methods, scope

Is this code safe in Java?

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        HelloWorld h = new HelloWorld();
        int y = h.getNumber(5);
        int z = h.getNumber (6);
        if (y == 10)
            System.out.println("true"); 
    }

    public int getNumber(int x) {
        int number = 5;
        number = number + x;
        return number;
    }

}
```

My co-worker says that int number will be placed on the stack and when getNumber returns it will be popped off and could potentially be overwritten.

Is the same code potentially unsafe in C?

Comment: Yes, it's fine. Ask your co-worker to explain why this is not safe, and maybe you can share with us.

Comment: Stop confusing _scope_ with anything occurring at runtime. _Scope_ is a compile time concept that defines where in source code you can use an identifier.

Comment: Your co-worker is wrong.

Comment: Your co-worker would probably prefer to return x+5 in getNumber method

Comment: Your coworker seems to have absolutely no idea how Java works.

Comment: No, it can explode in heat.

Comment: Write the code in C, then ask the question with the C tag if you'd like to ask about C. But again, you'll need to define "safe".

Answer (score 0):

The `HelloWorld` class has no fields, and is therefore immutable. You can call your `getNumber(x)` function as many times as you'd like, from any thread, using the same object, and it will always give the same result for the same argument.

Maybe your co-worker is recalling horror stories in C where you can have something like `static int number`, which "belongs" to the method and which would get overwritten. Or maybe she's thinking about "return by reference"; even if it were, you'd be referencing a brand-new object every time because `number` is newly instantiated for every method call.

Answer (score -2):

Your coworker is correct, sort of, but they apparently misunderstand what is going on.

```
    public int getNumber(int x) {
        int number = 5;
        number = number + x;
        return number;
    }
```

Yes the value of 5 + 5 or 5 + 6 will be placed on the stack, but there is no danger of them being overwritten, they will properly be placed into y or z.

I suspect the confusion is from C (this type code works fine in C as well), but for pointers instead of primitives. Returning a result of malloc from a function in C can be "challenging" if you don't do it right.

Comment: After JIT, it is unlikely that `number` will exist as a value on the stack. The entire operation will likely be done in registers, not on the stack. If the method gets inline by JIT, even the parameter and the return value will disappear as values on the stack. Conclusion: Coworker is wrong on all aspects.

Comment: That assumes knowledge of the VM internals. The JVM, at the asembler type level, is stack based. If it is in a register, or on the stack, does not matter in practice - what matters is that the value will not be trashed.